# sharepoint 2010 - How to force expiration policy to run everyday for all items on a list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Have on prem SharePoint 2010, setup expiration policy to run every day that triggers a workflow to create tasks and emails based on an alert day in a calculated column in the list.  Calculated columns have dates set to 7 days prior to a due date event.  Want the expiration policy to evaluate the entire list each day to create notification emails and tasks to the users of the list.

I have been successful in getting the policy to run the workflow every day, but it starts randomly within the window specified.  My assumptions: workflow will not run against an item on the list if the “Expiration Date” in less than 24 hours, I cannot modify that column directly, tightening the run window does not force all items to be evaluated every day.  Solution needs be done using designer or sharepoint, not custom code.

Does anyone have a workaround to force all items to be evaluated by the “Expiration Policy” every day?
On another issue, how to you force evaluation for items created under 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

In SP 2010 there are two timer jobs responsible for this task: "Information management policy" job and  "Expiration policy". [This blog post](http://www.wardpeter.com/?p=1055) may give you some more insight. There is also one more important thing: Information management policy should run before Expiration policy.